# Read in data in chunks via fread in R

Tags: r, datatable, fread

I am trying to read a huge dataset (> 25GB) in R. It doesn't fit in my PCs memory. But I think maybe it would be possible to work with the data, if it were in compressed (RData) format. As part of the process, I also have to change column classes to character, because some of the columns contain a mix of numbers and strings. How can this be done in `fread`?

The first part is always easy, we can use e.g. the following code to read 10m rows:

```
part1 <- fread(filename,sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, 
      nrows = 10000000,showProgress = TRUE, 
      colClasses=c(AA="character",BB="character"))
```

But if I try to read the second part of the file, I always get an error. I am using the following code to skip the first 1000000 rows, that were already read in before. Also I am setting `header` to `FALSE`

```
part2 <- fread(filename,sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = FALSE, 
      nrows = 10000000,skip=10000000,showProgress = TRUE, 
      colClasses=c(AA="character",BB="character"))
```

The error msg is:

```
Error in fread()  :  Column name 'AA' in colClasses[[1]] not found
```

Note: If we set `header = TRUE`, the error message still occurs.

I cannot give an example data set in this size, but I guess the problem is simply that the column names are missing if we use `skip`, and then they cannot be used when we set `colClasses`. Is there any way to use fread or do I have to use other packages?

Comment: have you tried reading the data without changing column names?

Comment: yep, I think you mean changing column classes I guess? I am getting errors like: `Bumped column 12 to type character on data row 2647747, field contains 'AC'...` It can actually be harmful, because all previously read in values are then simply converted to character (not necessarily lossless)

Comment: can you please run this code and check if you get any error `part1 <- fread(filename,sep = " ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE, 
      nrows = 2647746, showProgress = TRUE, 
      colClasses=c(AA="character",BB="character"))`

Comment: That is the same code as before, but lower nrows right? I dont expect an error because the code also runw with larger nrows. But I can try.

Comment: yes please try, I am suspecting something wrong at row 2647747

Comment: no it works fine. There is just a character ('AC'), whereas before it was only numbers from what I have seen. By the way, the problem also exists if you try to use `select` in combination with `skip` in `fread`